# Closing open chosen selects when a new one is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a handful of selects made with the jQuery chosen plugin. When one is opened, I want any others to automatically close. I've attempted to add a document onclick like this:

```
function close_selects(evt)
{
   if(evt.target.className != "chosen-select")
      $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:close");
   else
   {
      $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:close");
      evt.target.trigger("chosen:open");
   }
}
```

However, I can't seem to get that to do anything. What can I do to make other select boxes close?

Comment: This should be the default behaviour. If you check the examples on the chosen plugin website you'll see that this happens.

Comment: It doesn't happen with mine - I just end up with multiple boxes open at once.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply

```
$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:close");
  evt.target.trigger("chosen:open");
```

and bind the function close_selects() to $(".chosen-select") only.